# Create a dynamic C array for different structures

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-arrays

Is it possible to create a dynamic C array which works for all types. In this instance the dynamicArr would have to work for both struct1 and struct. What should the type of `structuretype` be to work for both struct1 and struct2 depending on the user initialization?

```c
typedef struct dynamicArr
{
    structuretype *arr;
    int capacity;
    int size;
}dynamicArr;
```

```c
typedef struct struct1
{
    int id;
    char *field1;
    char *field2;
    int num;
}struct1;
```

```c
typedef struct struct2
{
    char *field;
    int num1;
    int num2;
}struct2;
```

Comment: `void *`  or `union {struct1 *as_struct1; struct2 *as_struct2}` but then you need to somehow know what type it contains, typically by adding an enum field like  `enum {type_struct1, type_struct2}`.

Comment: You can also take a look to [How Linux Kernel implements generic linked list](https://hrishi.dev/linked/list,/linux,/linux/kernel/list/2020/11/20/generic-linkedin-list-c.html), is not intended for a dynamic array as in your case but the same logic can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct { 
   void *dataStructure; 
   int size; 
   int numElements; 
} dynamicArray; 
 
dynamicArray *init(int initialSize); 
 
void push(dynamicArray *A, void *element); 
 
void *pop(dynamicArray *A); 
 
void setElement(dynamicArray *A, int position, void *element); 
 
void *getElement(dynamicArray *A, int position);
```

You could probably add more functions to the list. Each would be responsible for resizing the array if the number of elements were to exceed the existing size of the array. Your external program would be responsible for casting each data element into a pointer of the data type you wished to use and vice versa.

Comment: You could probably add more functions to the list. Each would be responsible for resizing the array if the number of elements were to exceed the existing size of the array.

Your external program would be responsible for casting each data element into a pointer of the data type you wished to use and vice versa.

Im not professional in C. i did understand that the main problem could be that are two structs with different types?

Comment: How would I be able to store a variable which contains something from an element of the array. For example the id which is stored in dyna_arr.array[i].id

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `void*` (or an arry of `void*`). Be ware that you will loose any information about what the pointer is you are storing though.

A `void`-pointer will accept a pointer of any type without warning. `malloc()` for example returns `void*`, since you may want to use it for `char*`, `int*`, etc.

Storing objects in `void*` is very dangerous (especially if you plan to use multiple types) and should only be done with extreme caution, since, for example, this would compile without even a warning:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t number = 42;
    void* ptr = &number;
    uint32_t* new_number = ptr;

    printf("%i\n", *new_number);
}
```

This case can lead to serious memory corruption and thus may result in crashes and security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Making the structuretype `void*` should work although dangerous since you wouldn't have any way of knowing which type your pointer originally pointed to.
I would recommend adding some enum field to the dynamic array struct which would remember the original type of the data it's holding giving you the ability to cast it back "safely" when needed.